# 'java.lang.String' is deprecated in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

As the pictures says,

> 'java.lang.String' is deprecated

[image]

Android Studio version is 2.3.2.

How do I fix it?

Comment: show me your import

Comment: Umm. What? Is your JDK correct?

Comment: Hi 朱孟强, welcome to [so]. Can you please **[edit]** your question and post the actual code as text instead of a screenshot? Others can't copy and paste from your image. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira has no import for java.lang.String, is from standard library, i have fixed it by delete the .AndroidStudiox.x in my user folder

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you for your comment, i have fixed it by delete the  .AndroidStudiox.x folder in my user path