# android-studio Undeclare as deprecated

Tags: java, android-studio

How do I undeclare something as deprecated in android studio?

The specific case of mine: java.lang.String is declared as deprecated in every (also new) Project. I can't find any solution to this, neither at stackoverflow, the android studio settings/docs nor in the rest of the whole internet ':D

Android studio gave me (while declaring a variable) the option to declare 'String' as deprecated, and I wanted to try it, but thought I would to be able to undeclare it in the same easy fashion.. but nope.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402476/java-lang-string-is-deprecated-in-android-studio)?

Comment: The deprecation suppression annotation is `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`. I'm more confused about why it's saying `java.lang.String` is deprecated.

Comment: @DrZoo yep found that, i have the newest version, the install wizard got the path right and till I declared it deprecated it wasn't. But thanks nonetheless.

Comment: also i don't want to deactivate all deprecation-warnings, just editing what is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

That seems quite strange. Deprecating is something that you can't really do by yourself in the JDK.

You may be able to search for the annotations.xml in a directory via the SDK annotations tab and change it there. Or maybe there is a 'deannotate' option when right clicking it?

Comment: the search for the annotations.xml or other related entrys in the (broadly speaking) 'settings' of the IDE was not successfull.
[Picture with the actual Tooltip](https://imgur.com/a/8LOY7s1)