# 'java.lang.String' is deprecated in Android

Tags: android, string, deprecated

I have write simple TAG like this:

```
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
```

> String is deprecated

[image: IDE screenshot showing strikethrough through String]

Is there any alternative way available to use `String`?

Comment: String is not deprecated it can not probably its a Data Type not just some another class . add your code with question ..

Comment: Wait, what? `String` is one of the most basic non-primitive data types in Java. Can you show a screenshot of what you're seeing in the IDE? I'm having a hard time believing that.

Comment: It's just some weird IDE problem: ['java.lang.String' is deprecated in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402476/java-lang-string-is-deprecated-in-android-studio).

Comment: Wow i have first  time hear that a data type can also be depreacate

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen That's a really interesting question, shame it hasn't had an answer (and thus we can't flag as duplicate)

Comment: You know I heard about `String` being not recommended for the sake or `string`, but your case is not real for anyone else that I know of. Its not deprecated on my uptodate machine. Maybe you are missing something.

Comment: Since its clear String is not deprecated . You should Check JDK config in your android studio to fix this issue .. God !!! what a Nighmare .. Its over now...

Comment: @Yagnesh have u tried `invalidate-cache and restart android studio`

Comment: @NileshRathod yes i have try Clean Project,Rebuild Project and Invalidate-catch and restart many time but still showing String is depricated!!!!!

Comment: @Yagnesh check this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402476/java-lang-string-is-deprecated-in-android-studio#comment75848943_44402476

Comment: @Rifat Android Studio:3.4.1, JRE : 1.8.0_152  JVM: OpenJDK 64Bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comment in this [java-lang-string-is-deprecated-in-android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44402476/java-lang-string-is-deprecated-in-android-studio#comment75848943_44402476) question,

Remove folder **.AndroidStudioX.X** in your User folder and Restart IDE.

> **NOTE:** `AndroidStudioX.X` means if you are using Android Studio version
>   3.4 then .AndroidStudio3.4 will be there.
>
> Path will be like **Windows** : **`C:\Users\<PCNAME>\.AndroidStudio3.4`**
>
> **Linux/Ubuntu** : **`/home/yourname/.AndroidStudio3.4`**

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Comment: AndroidStudioX folder is not available!

Comment: AndroidStudioX.X means if you are using Android Studio version 3.4 then **AndroidStudio3.4** will be there. Path : `C:\Users\<PCNAME>\.AndroidStudio3.4`

Comment: i have use Ubuntu System how to get this if you know then please tell me

Comment: Then path will be `/home/yourname/.AndroidStudio3.4`

Comment: i got this folder and remove using command rm -rf .AndroidStudio3.4 its work! thanks bro